# How to understand tornado response request cycle in Django

Tags: django, request, webserver, response, tornado

I want to create a real time twitter streaming application using tornado and Django. The problem is I am not able to understand the role of Tornado here, and how will I use `view.py` `models.py` of Django in Tornado Web Server.

Below if the request response cycle of Django, could anybody explain to me how the tornado web server will play its role here. [image]

Few questions:

1- What will be role of `urls.py` file in Django since we will be routing all the urls from Tornado itself.

2- How will I connect to `models.py` to fetch rows for my tornado application.

I am looking into this github project [link](https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tornado fits roughly in the "web server" and "wsgi" parts of this diagram, and adds another section for Tornado RequestHandlers attached to the web server. When you create your `tornado.web.Application`, you will send some URLs to Tornado RequestHandlers and some to the Django WSGIContainer (which will in turn use the Django `urls.py`).

Using Django models from Tornado code is more challenging; my code from the last time I tried doing this is at https://gist.github.com/bdarnell/654157 (but note that this is quite old and I don't know if it will work any more)

Comment: How will you route some calls to Tornado and some to Django?

Comment: I am trying to run this project [link](https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo/tree/master/testsite) but it is running into errors. `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:`

Comment: The first level of routing is [here](https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo/blob/c5cad3378b1a49059c0d0ff8fec45933f74ae01c/testsite/tornado_main.py#L30): Some URLs are assigned Tornado handlers; everything else goes to the FallbackHandler, and from there to the django `urls.py`. I haven't touched Django in 5 years so I'm afraid I can't help with your Django 1.8 problems.

Comment: Could you share some links to build a proper web application using tornado ? The documentation of tornado is not very helpful, if you can refer some books that will be great. I want to learn step by step how each function/class works in tornado, and it could be used with aDatabase.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I wrote the Tornado documentation and I'd appreciate feedback about how you find it lacking. I don't know of anything better. (there's an O'Reilly book but it's rather out of date now)

Comment: How do you create tables for your application in Tornado? Like in we django we have ORM models which is super easy to start connecting SQL database. It seems to me like Tornado is more suitable for nosql right?

Comment: You should do some web series or ask someone to do it:) :) This is an awesome framework but lacks online support.

Answer (score 1):

This is tornado_main.py stored in one level with manage.py ... I've tested it with Django 1.8 ...

```
# coding=utf-8
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_project_dir.settings")

import django
django.setup()

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


from tornado.options import options, define, parse_command_line
import logging
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.wsgi


define('port', type=int, default=8004)
# tornado.options.options['log_file_prefix'].set(
#     '/var/www/myapp/logs/tornado_server.log')
tornado.options.parse_command_line()


class SomeHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    pass


def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r'/some_url/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)', SomeHandler),
        ],
        debug=True
    )

    logger.info("Tornado server starting...")

    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
    server.listen(options.port)

    try:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
        logger.info("Tornado server has stopped")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How are you routing your request to Django from here? I can't see any fall handler or it it not required since you are storing this `tornado_main.py` with `manage.py` ?

Comment: This file is working [link](https://github.com/omgbbqhaxx/django-1.6-tornado-demo/blob/master/torn.py) but it uses a `fallback handler` to transfer some `urls` to Django through '`wsgi`

Comment: Is your code base on github? I can through your whole source code. Share it if possible. Thanks

Comment: just run django and tornado separately: python manage.py runserver and python tornado_main.py

Comment: What will happen if I have defined same `url` in both tornado and django? Where will it go first?

Comment: There are two separate servers started on different ports so you cannot define same url ...

Comment: ... also if you plan use it for websockets https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket